# Как написать регулярное выражение на этот сценарий?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Необходимо запретить двойной slash, например, этот `//` и запретить `/` в конце строки.

```
dada/ НЕ ВАЛИДНО
asda ВАЛИДНО
dada//dad НЕ ВАЛИДНО
```

Comment: Удалите их, если они есть в конце строки  и всё. Зачем регулярка?

Comment: То есть запретить `\/(\/|$)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?!.*\/\/).*[^\/]$
```

`^` - начало строки
`(?!.*\/\/)` - негативный просмотр вперед на отсутствие в строке `//`
`.*` - ноль и более любых символов
`[^\/]$` - любой символ отличный от `/` в конце строки

Пример на JS:

```js
const str = `dada/
asda
dada//dad`;
const reg = /^(?!.*\/\/).*[^\/]$/m;
console.log(str.match(reg));
```